# Right align Text in table cell with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Site: [http://bit . ly/1qbtSEN](https://www.thetreecenter.com/product/thuja-green-giant/)

Well, I've tried every CSS selector combo I can think of, and I still cannot get **only** the **prices** column text to **right align** in the table cell. I can right align the table td but that also right aligns the text in the size column. . Any help with the correct selector would be fantastic.

Comment: float right on span works..

Comment: Can you specify which browsers you need to support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
table td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: `nth-child` isn't compatible with IE8.

Comment: IE8 using 2.1%, I do not believe that at that site they will enter:) Its time to stop supporting IE, let move to a normal browser :)

Comment: I would never have figured that out in a million years. Thanks for an elegant solution.

Comment: I'm in agreement about no longer supporting IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Put a class on your `td` with `text-align: right;`

[image]

Edit: If you're not worried about IE8 compatibility, CroaToa's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25002805/1355087 is the selector you want.

Comment: Good solution. I was trying to only use CSS. I appreciate the response though.